# dynamic Format at ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, csrss

this one is my report

[image]
This is my result (but iddescripcion is not visible)

[image]

my question is.

how do i get when iddescripcion=1,3,5,8 or 10 then valor is going to have this format 10,000 (not decimals)
when iddescripcion=2,4,6, or 9 then valor is going to have this format 1,000.0 or 3,000.1( one decimal)
and when iddescripcion=7,11 then valor is going to have this format  $2,389,012 (not decimalsa and $ before)
i believe the format i need add it at here but i do not have any idea how to do it..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply condition formatting using a `Switch` or `IIf` statement in the Text Box Expression value.

[image]

I put a simple example together using the following expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 1 or Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 2, Format(Fields!valor.Value, "N0")
    , Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 3 or Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 4, Format(Fields!valor.Value, "N1")
    , Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 5 or Fields!iddescripcion.Value = 6, Format(Fields!valor.Value, "$#,#"))
```

Basically just applying `Format` to *valor* based on *iddescripcion* for each row. This works for some simple data:

[image]

Hopefully you can adapt this for your example.